# Theoretically, can one do this to troubleshoot a circuit?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, multiway-switch

Could you do this to troubleshoot sets of switches and outlets that are connected in 4-way and 3-way patterns:

So if you unhook all wires that connect to outlets and switches in one circuit, could you theoretically find the first “live” black/red wires and start putting the circuit together one switch/outlet at a time? Leaving all pigtailed wires connected so as not to make a huge mess.

So for example, start with the first switch or outlet, connect wires, test where it will flow, document, then get the next outlet/switch set up, etc??

Thanks I have a room where everything got messed up and there are multiple outlets and switches on the same circuit.

Comment: Generally I'm not a fan of "unhook all devices and splay the wires all out" because at least once a month we get a photo of exactly that from a novice who asks "what goes to what?"  In fact, **the knowledge is stored in how the wires are connected presently** and of course the person just destroyed that to get their photo.   But if you're willing to "ring out" the whole shebang, maybe with a handful of resistors so you can positively identify certain pairs from the far end - then map it all... then sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually not just "OK" but *a great idea*. The problem is that many people simply don't have the patience. They think there is a magic way it must, *of course*, work so they upload a diagram and ask us to fix it for them. But even a simple 3-way circuit can be connected several ways that are legitimate and a few ways that are not (but which still "work"). So yes, go ahead with your plan - one switch, fixture, device or receptacle at a time.

If you have not already done all the unhooking, *take pictures of everything before you unhook anything!* Even if some things are currently not working, odds are that the previous configuration was *mostly* correct. On the other hand, if it is already all disconnected then you have to just hack away at it, one cable at a time.

Comment: Taking pictures before undoing connections will help afterwards.

Comment: Pictures have to be really thorough to cover all connections.  More specific markings can be hugely helpful too, using tape and/or pen on the wires and their terminals.

Comment: I would recommend **strongly _emphasizing_** the somewhat buried "one switch, fixture, device or receptacle **at a time**."

Comment: attaching labels. or marking the wires helps too